# Angular Universal TTFb Take a lot Time to Response

Tags: node.js, angular, optimization

I use Angular with  SSR  Nodejs Server it's Take About 16s to Response by Rendering Html also after Optmize the Angular app Performance

I tried to Compress html

I use @nguniversal/express-engine with Lazy Loading, Angular 6 
and Express app

[light house test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvm3B.png)

[response time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jd0TZ.png)

> my code

```
enableProdMode();

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5410;
const arBundle = require('./server/ar/main');
const enBundle = require('./server/en/main');
export const languageEngines = [{
  id: 'en',
  base: '/en'
},
{
  id: 'ar',
  base: '/ar'
},
{
  id: 'en',
  base: '/'
},
];

app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
  bootstrap: enBundle.AppServerModuleNgFactory,
  providers: [
    provideModuleMap(enBundle.LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
  ]
}));
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', join(__dirname, 'browser'));

app.get('*.*', express.static((__dirname + '/browser'), {
  maxAge: '1y'
}));

languageEngines.forEach(languageEngine => {

  app.get(languageEngine.base + "*", function (req, res) {

    res.render(__dirname + "/browser/" + languageEngine.id + "/index.html", {
      req: req,
      res: res
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Have you found solution for it?